# Using combinations to find binominal tree

Tags: python, combinations

I have the below

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce
from math import prod


invoice = [['in_1', 1234, 0.9, 30],['in_2', 9750, 0.97, 30], ['in_3', 4698, 0.98, 30], ['in_4',2135, 0.95, 30]]
```

The first element is the invoice code, the second the amount, the third is probability and the fourth the number of days.

Using combinations I can work out the likelihood of two invoices being paid. This is the product of the third element. I get this by using the below:

```
for i in range(1, len(invoice)+1):

    for x in list(combinations(invoice, i)):

        name, exposure, pd, time = zip(*x)

        exposure = sum(exposure)
        pd = prod(pd)

        print (pd)
```

However, what I am trying to do is find the probability of results of the above being the postive output and those not chose being the negative output.

For instance, one of the lines created by the above will be:

```
(['in_1', 1234, 0.9, 30], ['in_2', 9750, 0.97, 30])
```

This will create a pd of (0.9 * 0.97) = 0.873. However, i am looking for this to be the postive outcome and the negative outcome to be the two invoices not chosen.

Is there a better combination tool to use which can give the required output.

Comment: If you are going to iterate over the combinations then there is no need to first turn them into a list. I don't know what you mean by "However, i am looking for this to be the postive outcome and the negative outcome to be the two invoices not chosen." -- could you elaborate? What is the intended outcome? A negative probability?

Comment: Me too. See [ask]. It's unclear. What's your definition of 'outcome', 'chosen invoices', etc? You need to define your desired set of combinations.